# filename comparison with wildcard

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I am working on a script and I need to compare a filename to another one and look for specific changes (in this case a "(x)" added to a filename when OS X needs to add a file to a directory, when a filename already exists) so this is an excerpt of the script, modified to be tested without the rest of it.

```
#!/bin/bash

p2_s2="/Path/to file (name)/containing - many.special chars.docx.gdoc"
next_line="/Path/to file (name)/containing - many.special chars.docx (1).gdoc"
file_ext=$(echo "${p2_s2}" | rev | cut -d '.' -f 1 | rev)
file_name=$(basename "${p2_s2}" ".${file_ext}")
file_dir=$(dirname "${p2_s2}")

esc_file_name=$(printf '%q' "${file_name}")
esc_file_dir=$(printf '%q' "${file_dir}")
esc_next_line=$(printf '%q' "${next_line}")

if [[ ${esc_next_line} =~ ${esc_file_dir}/${esc_file_name}\ \(?\).${file_ext} ]]
 then
  echo "It's a duplicate!"
fi
```

What I'm trying to do here is detect if the file next_line is a duplicate of p2_s2. As I am expecting multiple duplicates, next_line can have a (1) appended at the end of a filename or any other number in brackets (Although I am sure no double digits). As I can't do a simple string compare with a wildcard in the middle, I tried using the "=~" operator and escaping all the special chars. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trim `ps2_s2`'s extension, trim `next_line`'s extension **including** the number inside the parenthesis and see if you get the same file name. If you do - it's a duplicate. In order to do so, `[[` allows us to perform a comparison between a string and a [Glob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob).

I used [*extglob*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob)'s `+( ... )` pattern, so I can use `+([0-9])` to match the number inside the parenthesis. Notice that *extglob* is enabled by `shopt -s extglob`.

```
#!/bin/bash

p2_s2="/Path/to/ps2.docx.gdoc"
next_line="/Path/to/ps2(1).docx.gdoc"

shopt -s extglob
if [[ "${p2_s2%%.*}" = "${next_line%%\(+([0-9])\).*}" ]]; then
    printf '%s is a duplicate of %s\n' "$next_line" "$p2_s2"
fi
```

## EDIT:

I now see that you've edited your question, so in case this solution is not enough, I'm positive that it'll be a good template to work with.

Answer (score 0):

The `(1)` in `next_line` doesn't come before the final `.` it comes before the second to final `.` in the original filename but you only strip off a single `.` as the extension.

So when you generate the comparison filename you end up with `/Path/to\ file\ \(name\)/containing\ -\ many.special\ chars.docx\ \(?\).gdoc` which doesn't match what you expect.

If you had added `set -x` to the top of your script you'd have seen what the shell was actually doing and seen this.

What does OS X actually do in this situation? Does it add `(#)` before `.gdoc? Does it add it before`.docx`? Does it depend on whether OS X *knows* what the filename is (it is some type it can open natively)?

Comment: Sorry for that, hhis was a traditional PEBKAC, caused by me replacing the actual entries I use for testing with made-up ones. Unfortunately, my test script has the "(1)" positioned correctly, after .docx and before .gdoc.

Comment: but adding "set -x" revealed what's wrong:
`${esc_file_dir}/${esc_file_name}\ \(?\).${file_ext}` 
is interpreted as 
`/Path/to\ file\ \(name\)/containing\ -\ many.special\ chars.docx \(?\).gdoc`
and not 
`/Path/to\ file\ \(name\)/containing\ -\ many.special\ chars.docx\ \(?\).gdoc`
however adding a single additional backslash produces a syntax error (duh) and adding two more produces this output: 
`/Path/to\ file\ \(name\)/containing\ -\ many.special\ chars.docx\\ \(?\).gdoc`
any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Construct the filename in a variable and use it (unquoted) in the `=~` test. See if that helps. bash has had various quoting/escaping issues on the RHS of `=~` over the years.